# Mechanical realization of three dimensional spinors

Tags: education, spinors

This question asks for a mechanical device

- whose configuration space is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere $\mathbb S^3$;
- which contains a rigid body, which has rotation $R(q)$ (an element of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ for each configuration $q \in \mathbb S^3$).
- The map $R : \mathbb S^3 \to \mathrm{SO}(3)$ is topologically the double cover $\mathbb S^3 \to \mathbb{RP}^3$.

Now, the Dirac belt trick almost satisfies these requirements, except that reasonable physical realizations will have way too many degrees of freedom: you need to quotient out the movement of the soft belt. It should be possible to replace these belts by more rigid mechanisms with some designing effort.

It is not surprising that such a device *can* theoretically be built, but the theorems guaranteeing this produce huge machines with thousands of parts. So I would like to see if there is any "elegant" designs that are actually practical.

Answer (score 0):

"The spinor linkage -- a mechanical implementation of the plate trick" by
Alexander E. Holroyd

Abstract: The plate trick or belt trick is a striking physical demonstration of properties of the double cover of the three-dimensional rotation group by the sphere of unit quaternions or spinors. The two ends of a flexible object are continuously rotated with respect to each other. Surprisingly, the object can be manipulated so as to avoid accumulating twists. We present a new mechanical linkage that implements this task. It consists of a sequence of rigid bodies connected by hinge joints, together with a purely mechanical control mechanism. It has one degree of freedom, and the motion is generated by simply turning a handle.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.01681v1

Comment: If I understand correctly, this only has one degree of freedom, rendering it a double cover of $\mathbb S^1$. But this is simple to achieve: any $2:1$ gear will do!